# How is an instance of a dictionary changing the original

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

current dictionary is just an instance right so how is it that it is adding to the originals.

second question, why is currentDictionary.Add("bug", KeyCode.N) throwing an error. thanks in advance!

```
 public Dictionary<string, KeyCode> KeyBinds {get; private set;}
 public Dictionary<string, KeyCode> ActionBinds {get; private set;}
 private string bindName;

 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
    KeyBinds = new Dictionary<string, KeyCode>();
    ActionBinds = new Dictionary<string, KeyCode>();

    BindKey("UP", KeyCode.W);
    BindKey("DOWN", KeyCode.S);
    BindKey("LEFT", KeyCode.A);
    BindKey("RIGHT", KeyCode.D);
    BindKey("ROLL", KeyCode.Space);

    BindKey("USETOOL", KeyCode.Mouse1);

    BindKey("ZOOM IN", KeyCode.Equals);
    BindKey("ZOOM OUT", KeyCode.Minus);

    BindKey("ACT1", KeyCode.Alpha1);
    BindKey("ACT2", KeyCode.Alpha2);
    BindKey("ACT3", KeyCode.Alpha3);
    BindKey("ACT4", KeyCode.Alpha4);
    BindKey("ACT5", KeyCode.Alpha5);
    BindKey("ACT6", KeyCode.Alpha6);
    BindKey("ACT7", KeyCode.Alpha7);
    BindKey("ACT8", KeyCode.Alpha8);
    BindKey("ACT9", KeyCode.Alpha9);
    BindKey("ACT10", KeyCode.Alpha0);
 }

 void Update()
 {
    Debug.Log(KeyBinds.Count);
 }

 public void BindKey(string key, KeyCode keyBind)
 {
    Dictionary<string, KeyCode> currentDictionary = KeyBinds;

    if (key.Contains("ACT"))
    {
        currentDictionary = ActionBinds;
    }
    if (!currentDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        currentDictionary.Add(key, keyBind);
        UIManager.MyInstance.UpdateKeyText(key, keyBind);
    }
    else if (currentDictionary.ContainsValue(keyBind))
    {
        string myKey = currentDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == keyBind).Key;

        currentDictionary[myKey] = KeyCode.None;
        UIManager.MyInstance.UpdateKeyText(key, KeyCode.None);
    }
    currentDictionary.Add("bug", KeyCode.N);
    currentDictionary[key] = keyBind;
    UIManager.MyInstance.UpdateKeyText(key, keyBind);
    bindName = string.Empty;
}
```

I tried to add to the dictionary using currentDictionary.Add("bug", KeyCode.N) in order to see if it altered the original count.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

When you add an item to `currentDictionary`, the `KeyBinds` dictionary also changes since `currentDictionary` points to `KeyBinds` in memory. In other words `currentDictionary` and `KeyBinds` **refer to the same memory location. They are not independent copies.**

With regard to the exception, I assume you are getting an

```
ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added. Key: bug'
```

The reason is that *you are trying to add the `"bug"` key more than once* (`BindKey()` is called multiple times). To confirm if adding items to `currentDictionary` altered the original count, no need for the line

```
currentDictionary.Add("bug", KeyCode.N);
```

Delete this line and use the debugger to inspect the values of `currentDictionary` and `KeyBinds` just after an `Add()` call.

**Edit:** Consider the following example to see the difference between *reference types* and *value types*:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var dict2 = dict1;
dict1.Add("a", 1);
Console.WriteLine("dict1 count: " + dict1.Count);
Console.WriteLine("dict2 count: " + dict2.Count);
```

Output:

```
dict1 count: 1
dict2 count: 1
```

```
float num1 = 1;
float num2 = num1;
num2++;
Console.WriteLine("num1: " + num1);
Console.WriteLine("num2: " + num2);
```

Output:

```
num1: 1
num2: 2
```

- When you assign a reference type to another then they both reference the same object. **Operations on one variable affect** the object referenced by the other variable. Hence `currentDictionary` affects the original dictionary.
- When you assign a value type to another then there are **two independent copies in memory**. Hence `num1` and `num2` have different values.

Comment: thank you for your response that helps clear it up a bit, however how is it these variables act independently float num1 = 1;
        float num2;

        num2 = num1;
        num2++;
        Debug.Log(num1);
        Debug.Log(num2);

Comment: num1 = 1, num2 = 2, shouldnt they be the same like the dictonaries

Comment: There is a difference between reference and value types. When you assign a value type to other value type then there are two *independent copies* in memory. `Dictionary` is a reference type, `float` is a value type.